# Involved to or Involved in

Tags: prepositions, verbs, grammaticality-in-context, word-in-context

Read this context:

> Reading all of your speech from a note may give you confidence and ensure that nothing is forgotten or omitted, however it is the least interesting option for delivering your speech. you will find it more difficult to see your audience, and make it harder for them to get ........ to you.

In this context we want to fill the blank with one of this words:

> a. prevented b. puzzled c. distracted d. involved

In the book in which I found this test, the answer is "d. involved". Isn't the preposition of involved "in/with"? Now, why the answer is involved "to"? I thought it the answer is distracted to but it also has not a  appropriate meaning in this context.

Comment: @Andrew Yes it is the actual quote. This is from a cloze test. The context is not written by a native English but it was part of an exam which is written in this book as an example for cloze tests. So you mean that none of the answers is correct and we can't say get involved to?

Comment: @Andrew . Please submit your answer so I can choose it as the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is the actual quote (as you say) then first sentence is already not idiomatic English.  It should be:

> Reading **your whole** speech from **your notes** ...

"All of your speech" makes sense, but I just don't feel it's natural in this context.  Also, for something like a speech or lecture, we write *notes*, plural, and read back from those notes.  A "note" is something short, written for a particular purpose or to a particular person (or group).

None of the answer choices is really correct.  The verb "involve" takes the prepositions "in" or "with".

> I didn't want to get **involved with** them -- they're too radical for me.
>
> I wanted to get more **involved in** my wife's family business, but her father wouldn't allow it.

"Involved to" is not idiomatic.  Also, it's not really idiomatic to say the audience gets *involved in* a speaker.  They can get involved in something like a *speech* or a *movie*, but not in a person (although you can get involved in someone's *life*).

Instead, in this context I would use a verb like "connect", or "relate".

> Reading entirely from your notes is the least interesting way to deliver a speech. When you do this, you will find it more difficult to **engage with** your audience, and they will find it more difficult to **relate to** what you are saying.

I recommend finding a different book, preferably one written by native speakers.

Comment: I have voted this answer up because it makes a lot of sense. Good job, Andrew. I would reck his advice if I were you, titansarus.